# Как добавить в TextView текст из файла?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textview

Есть `TextView`. Как добавить текст в него не с файла  `strings.xml` по `name`, а из файла что хранится на компьютере? Или же как в `strings.xml` добавить значение из файла, чтобы уже потом в `TextView` взять из `strings`?

Comment: копировать/вставить? или в чем именно пробема, автогенерация strings.xml из текстов на компьютере? напрямую вы не можете указать для андроид-приложения ресурсы на компьютере, потому что никто не будет таскать ваш компьютер за своим телефоном, чтобы получить их, сначала эти ресурсы должны быть импортированы в разрабатываемый проект

Comment: @pavloff , уже разобрался, спасибо. Текстовые документы будут на сервере. Не знал как их содержимое импортировать в strings.xml или сразу в textview в vayout-е.